# How to consume GTFS feed in Google Map v3 using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, unzip, gtfs

I'm first time trying to use GTFS(General Transit Feed Specification) with Google Maps as per the Google developers page i have understood the concept of .txt files which are used as feed and for making a demo i downloaded a transit zip files from Google developers page. but I'm not getting how to use those transit files to show information on map. I tried to search tutorial for the same but could not find anything useful. Do i need to parse all those files to show in map or there is something different implementation.

I'm confused.

Please bear me with my lack of knowledge regarding GTFS.

Comment: GTFS = Google Transit Feed Specification if anyone else was wondering.. https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/

Comment: yes i have gone through the documentation but i did not find any useful resource of how to access the transit zip files in Maps

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display stops and routes on a map, you can use [gtfs-to-geojson](https://github.com/blinktaginc/gtfs-to-geojson) to convert GTFS to GeoJSON that can be loaded onto a Google Map or Mapbox.

Install `gtfs-to-geojson`:

```
npm install gtfs-to-geojson -g
```

Setup a `config.json` file, then run:

```
gtfs-to-geojson --configPath /path/to/your/config.json
```

The tool will output a folder of GeoJSON files.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, GTFS is not yet "plug and play" ready - there's no simple way to just load up a GTFS dataset and work with it or query it on Google Maps, using either Google's web interface or their Javascript libraries.

Getting this working requires:

1. Setting up a (SQL) database and importing the GTFS dataset into that database.
2. Setting up a query system to get the information you want out of the SQL database (e.g., a web front-end that queries the database backend).

Feel free to look at some examples from around the web:

- [Broader GTFS discussion](http://openplans.org/2012/08/the-openplans-guide-to-gtfs-data/), and a link to a PostgreSQL + R solution from James Wong
- [MongoDB + node.js from Brendan Nee](https://github.com/brendannee/node-gtfs)