# How to make a shapes.txt in GTFS

Tags: masstransit, gtfs

I've been compiling data to make a GTFS but i want to know what are some of the GIS systems that people are using to create the shapes.txt. What are some of the problems you are running into and what are some of the benefits of your workflow.

Comment: What format are your data in? Having just read the GTFS documentation, it would seem that shapes.txt is simply in csv format, so I'm not sure you would need to use a GIS to generate the file.

Comment: I suppose i'm having trouble understanding how it works. If it's a csv file how can it be projected.

Comment: There is a partial answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095557/how-to-consume-gtfs-feed-in-google-map-v3-using-javascript So, yes, it would seem you do need to import it into a database. In that case, I would suggest Postgis, as it supports geometry types, and has an ST_Transform function to convert from one coordinate system to another.